# SUM DISTINCT MYSQL | WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, sum, distinct

I would like to get results based on SUM from table (history), where username contains 'red' and grouped by month. here the query :

```
select month(date),
SUM(CASE WHEN status='success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_sucess, 
SUM(CASE WHEN status='failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_failed
from history
where date between '201305%' AND '201311%'  AND username like '%@red%' 
GROUP BY month(history.date);
```

the results :

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| month(date) | total_sucess | total_failed |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
|          5 |        10960 |         3573 |
|          6 |         2336 |         1202 |
|          7 |         2211 |         1830 |
|          8 |         5312 |         3125 |
|          9 |         9844 |         5407 |
|         10 |         6351 |         3972 |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

the question is , how do I get distinct total_success and total_failed SUM? just in one query ?

I've tried using this

```
select month(tgl),
SUM(CASE WHEN status='success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_sucess, 
SUM(DISTINCT (username) CASE WHEN status='success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as distinct_total_sucess, 
SUM(CASE WHEN status='failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_failed,
SUM(DISTINCT (username) CASE WHEN status='failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as distinct_failed_sucess
from history_auth
where tgl between '201305%' AND '201311%'  AND username like '%@t.sel%' 
GROUP BY month(history_auth.tgl);
```

but get error sql syntax... i have no idea with this :(

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you mean for each username, just count 1 success and 1 failure?

Comment: post your excepted result also

Comment: If that's what you want, you need to write a subquery that groups by username, status, and month.

Answer (score 3):

Best I can make out of your requirement is that you want the number of distinct usernames each month that succeeded / failed.

If so I think you need a pair of sub selects to get those figures.

Rejigged the query (adding another sub select to get the 6 months, rather than relying on all months being represented.

```
SELECT Sub1.aMonth,
SUM(CASE WHEN history.status='success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_sucess, 
SUM(CASE WHEN history.status='failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_failed,
IFNULL(SuccessCount, 0),
IFNULL(FailedCount, 0)
FROM 
(
    SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB('2013-11-01', INTERVAL 0 MONTH)) AS aMonth 
    UNION SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB('2013-11-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
    UNION SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB('2013-11-01', INTERVAL 2 MONTH)) 
    UNION SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB('2013-11-01', INTERVAL 3 MONTH))
    UNION SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB('2013-11-01', INTERVAL 4 MONTH))
    UNION SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB('2013-11-01', INTERVAL 5 MONTH)) 
    UNION SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB('2013-11-01', INTERVAL 6 MONTH))
) Sub1
LEFT OUTER JOIN history 
ON MONTH(history.date) = Sub1.aMonth
AND username LIKE '%@red%' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT MONTH(date) AS aMonth, COUNT(DISTINCT username) AS SuccessCount
    FROM history
    WHERE status='success'
    AND username LIKE '%@red%' 
    GROUP BY MONTH(date)
) Sub2
ON Sub1.aMonth = Sub2.aMonth
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT MONTH(date) AS aMonth, COUNT(DISTINCT username) AS FailedCount
    FROM history
    WHERE status='failed'
    AND username LIKE '%@red%' 
    GROUP BY MONTH(date)
) Sub3
ON Sub1.aMonth = Sub3.aMonth
GROUP BY Sub1.aMonth, SuccessCount, FailedCount
```